# How can I disable built in snippets from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type > in a .php file inside Visual Studio Code, it proposes an HTML snippet like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

First time I saw it thought it was super cool, problem is that it proposes the snippet every time I close a tag. I thought this was coming from Intellisense for PHP so I deactivate the extension, but it keeps proposing the snippet. I can add my won snippets, but I can't find where are the built in ones.

Even more strange, At my office VS Code doesn't have this behaivour, it only does it at my home PC. I'm pretty sure I have configured both in the same way

#

This snippet apparently comes from HTML files. If in an .html file I press ctrl-space I see this precise snippet. So looks like .php are a derivative of .html or something, but the behaivour in an .html is different than the .php one

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this exact example, but the built in snippets that caused problems for me seemed to mostly come from "Emmet" (https://emmet.io/) which is built in to VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).

I disabled it by adding this to my "settings.json" file:

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```

*(you can find it by clicking the small icon that looks like a file with an arrow curving into it in the top right of the screen when you have settings open)*

If you want a way to still use the Emmet snippets, you can add a keyboard shortcut to your keybindings.json file:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+cmd+e",
  "command": "editor.emmet.action.expandAbbreviation",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

*(you can find it by clicking the small icon that looks like a file with an arrow curving into it in the top right of the screen when you have Keyboard Shortcuts open)*

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following file:

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php\snippets\php.code-snippets`

These are default snippets that come with built-in extensions. I've not found any other way to disable them while keeping all the other features (custom snippets, path intellisense).